How can I pass 'header_symbol_search' to 'disabled_features' in vue-tradingview-widgets Chart?
Basically, I need to disable symbol search from the chart, because 'allow_symbol_change' in options, only disables dropdown, but not keyboard input.
How symbol search looks like.
Here's example of options that passed to Chart component. But as i mentioned earlier I need to pass disabled_features:['header_symbol_search'] too.
<Chart class="chart"
         :options="{
  theme: 'dark',
  autosize:true,
  allow_symbol_change:false,
  calendar:false,
  interval:'H',
  symbol:'BTCUSDT'
}"/>

Is there any way to do this? Or has anyone done something like that?

See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . You need a reproducible example that gives a clear idea what you do, preferable a live demo because this is something that needs to be debugged and fiddled with

Well, seems like disabled_options don't work in this widget(advanced charts). I've tried importing it as usual HTML and JS script, and then pass this data, but it still don't work.
I`ve also tried "manually" removing div, which works as Symbol search, but due to it's structure (chart placed inside iframe), i couldn't access it due to CORS policy.
